# Calculating total Length of all string properties in an object

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have an object with 100s of properties.
they are all strings.How can I calculate the total length of all properties put together?

MyAttempt:

```
    public static int GetPropertiesMaxLength(object obj)
    {
        int totalMaxLength=0;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in info)
        {
           // ? 
            totalMaxLength+=??
        }
        return totalMaxLength;
    }
```

Suggestions?

Comment: An object with _hundreds_ of properties? Sounds like you might want to consider using a `Dictionary<string, string>` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by the total length of all properties? Their values?

Comment: Can I please ask why you have an object with 100 properties in the first place, and not a list or an array with a fitting object(that holds a string again?)

Comment: @Rob myPropertyString.Length. Yes their values

Comment: @HCP .It's not my object but client object I am intereacting with

Comment: @user231465 : are all properties public?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a property given its [`PropertyInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) use the `GetValue` method passing the containing object and no parameters (unless this is an indexed property – which would make things more complicated):

```
public static int GetPropertiesMaxLength(object obj) {
  int totalMaxLength=0;
  Type type = obj.GetType();
  PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
  foreach (PropertyInfo property in info) {
     if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string)) {
       string value = property.GetValue(obj, null) as string;
       totalMaxLength += value.Length;
    }
  }
  return totalMaxLength;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using LINQ [Sum()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.sum.aspx) and [Where()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.where.aspx) methods:

```
public static int GetTotalLengthOfStringProperties(object obj)
{            
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> info = type.GetProperties();

    int total = info.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof (String))
                    .Sum(pr => (((String) pr.GetValue(obj, null)) 
                               ?? String.Empty).Length);
    return total;
}
```

PS: To *enable* LINQ you've to add `using System.Linq`;

**EDIT:** More generic approach

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets a total length of all string-type properties
/// </summary>
/// <param name="obj">The given object</param>
/// <param name="anyAccessModifier">
/// A value which indicating whether non-public and static properties 
/// should be counted
/// </param>
/// <returns>A total length of all string-type properties</returns>
public static int GetTotalLengthOfStringProperties(
                                  object obj, 
                                  bool anyAccessModifier)
{
    Func<PropertyInfo, Object, int> resolveLength = (p, o) =>        
        ((((String) p.GetValue(o, null))) ?? String.Empty).Length;

    Type type = obj.GetType();
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> info = anyAccessModifier 
        ? type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | 
                             BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
        : type.GetProperties();    

    int total = info.Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof (String))
                    .Sum(pr => resolveLength(pr, obj));
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
public static int GetPropertiesMaxLength(object obj)
{
    int totalMaxLength=0;
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in info)
    {
        totalMaxLength+= property.GetValue(obj, null).ToString().Length;
    }
    return totalMaxLength;
}
```

Comment: This will mean, for example, that an integer typed property with value 12345 will add five to the length, as will one valued -1234.

Comment: I agree, but the OP stated that all the properties are strings

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all properties are public:

```
Object objValue = property.GetValue(obj, null);
if(objValue  != null)
  totalMaxLength += obj
Value.ToString().Length;
```

If the properties are not all public then you'll have to combine the needed binding flags like this

```
Object objValue = property.GetValue(obj, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static /* etc... */, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
    public static int GetPropertiesMaxLength(object obj)
    {
        int totalMaxLength = 0;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in info)
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj, null) as string;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                totalMaxLength += value.Length;
            }
        }
        return totalMaxLength;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        int count = value.GetType()
            .GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof (string) && p.CanRead)
            .Select(p => (string) p.GetValue(value, null))
            .Sum(s => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) ? 0 : s.Length));
```

You could alter the where clause to your needs. For example if you want to exclude statics or privates, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int GetPropertiesMaxLength(object obj)
{
    Type type = obj.GetType();
    PropertyInfo[] info = type.GetProperties();
    int totalMaxLength = info.Sum(prop => (prop.GetValue(prop, null) as string).Length);        
    return totalMaxLength;
}
```

Try this.